# How to prevent firestore snapshot, printing results too many times?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore DocumentSnapshot returns 54 DocumentId's. I pushed each id into one array but now array is printing out 54 arrays each with an increasing index.

I have tried function closure but get same results

```
 var newArray=[];
 this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('machine', '==',true))
 .get()
 .subscribe((snapshot) => {
   snapshot.forEach(doc => {
     const dataNew = doc.id;
     newArray.push(doc.id)
     for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
       console.log(newArray[i]);
     }
  });
});
```

I expect the array to output once for each index:

```
2JFH4NBvEIWB6B5gHuO5J3peI0h1
2JFH4NBvEIWB6B5gHuO5J3peI0h1
2vslBGmfMtUsTt7EZWTvBsqLTjg1
2JFH4NBvEIWB6B5gHuO5J3peI0h1
2vslBGmfMtUsTt7EZWTvBsqLTjg1
53UQPRDjHZZjyA6UsQvr8TbgY372
2JFH4NBvEIWB6B5gHuO5J3peI0h1
2vslBGmfMtUsTt7EZWTvBsqLTjg1
53UQPRDjHZZjyA6UsQvr8TbgY372
5IqWO1zlCAhTiFreUpUaejBqbNY2
2JFH4NBvEIWB6B5gHuO5J3peI0h1
2vslBGmfMtUsTt7EZWTvBsqLTjg1
53UQPRDjHZZjyA6UsQvr8TbgY372
5IqWO1zlCAhTiFreUpUaejBqbNY2
6V9R849TmBYQYiYbKgTiM1agVr92
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

1. Loops over the documents
2. In each iteration, adds the document to the array
3. Then (still inside the iteration) loops over the array
4. Prints each document

On the first iteration, this will give you:

- Document 1

On the second iteration:

- Document 1
- Document 2

In the third iteration:

- Document 1
- Document 2
- Document 3

And since you're running these all after each other, you get:

- Document 1
- Document 1
- Document 2
- Document 1
- Document 2
- Document 3

To prevent this from happening, move the inner loop outside of the outter iteration:

```
snapshot.forEach(doc => {
  const dataNew = doc.id;
  newArray.push(doc.id)
});
for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(newArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `snapshot.forEach` method is going to loop for every line of result.

You are also nesting your own `for` loop inside of it.

That means the first item in snapshot is going to execute the `for` loop with 1 item in the array, then second item will execute it with 2 items in the array, the third with 3 items, etc...

You need to extract your `for` loop out of the `forEach`:

```
var newArray=[];
this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('machine', '==',true))
    .get()
    .subscribe((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            const dataNew = doc.id;
            newArray.push(doc.id)
        });
       for (var i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
           console.log(newArray[i]);
       }
});
```